# Error with authenticated user using guard and can to access to some model

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm using lighthouse-php to make a graphql api and I'm having a trouble changing middleware (it will be deprecated in new versions) directive to guard.

```
extend type Query @middleware(checks: ["auth:api"]) {
    task(id: ID @eq): Task @can(ability: "view" find:"id") @find
    mytasks: [Task!]!
}
```

Using this code works well. I mean, the system checks if the user is logged and check against the policy if the user can access to their task, but when I try to change the `@middleware` directive to `@guard` directive like this:

```
extend type Query @guard(with: ["api"]){
    task(id: ID @eq): Task @can(ability: "view" find:"id") @find
    mytasks: [Task!]!
}
```

Always return that the user is unauthenticated. But, in the last case if I remove the @can directive the system check if the user is logged or not (but I need to check against the policy if the user can access the specified task).

I'm using these versions of packages:

```
"joselfonseca/lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth": "^3.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground": "^2.0",
    "nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.8"
```

Have somebody experimented with this trouble?
thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into exactly the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I did. I just wrote the solution for other people. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

we must to set up the config/auth.php file with the following:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've found another solution mentioned in the documentation:

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/security/authentication.html#global

So in short, I needed to add the AttemptAuthentication middleware to the lighthouse config. I use this with @auth(guard: "api") added to all my types.